# Running a conditional through several dataframes stored in a list R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, conditional-statements, lapply

I have a list of dataframes with the following format that I want to run a conditional through:

```
IDn = c("ChrM", "ChrM" ,"ChrM" ,"ChrM" ,"ChrM")   
posn = c(2,5,7,8,9)
met = c(2,0,4,1,0)
nmet = c(2,1,0,2,0)
bd = c(3,3,0,8,10)
dfp = data.frame(IDn,posn,met,nmet,bd)

      IDn     posn met  nmet bd
    1 ChrM    2    2    2    3
    2 ChrM    5    0    1    3
    3 ChrM    7    4    0    0
    4 ChrM    8    1    2    8
    5 ChrM    9    0    0    10

dfp[crit] <- (dfp[met]+dfp[nmet]>=4) & (dfp[met]>=dfp[bd])
```

The thing is that every df within the list has a different name, stored under names2

```
names2[crit] <- as.numeric((names2[met]+names2[nmet]>=4) & (names2[met]>=names2[bd]))
```

`[crit]` being a new column to store a 0 or 1 value. I tried to run this with `lapply`, but had had no luck thus far. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what is going wrong with your `lapply`-code (it is always good to include the code you tried into your question), but the following should work:

```
# creating a list
dflist <- list(d1=dfp, d2=dfp)

# updating the dataframes in your list
dflist <- lapply(dflist, function(x) {x$crit <- (x$met + x$nmet >= 4) & (x$met>=x$bd); x})

# or:
dflist <- lapply(dflist, function(x) {cbind(x, crit = (x$met + x$nmet >= 4) & (x$met>=x$bd))})
```

which results in the following list:

```
> dflist
$d1
   IDn posn met nmet bd  crit
1 ChrM    2   2    2  3 FALSE
2 ChrM    5   0    1  3 FALSE
3 ChrM    7   4    0  0  TRUE
4 ChrM    8   1    2  8 FALSE
5 ChrM    9   0    0 10 FALSE

$d2
   IDn posn met nmet bd  crit
1 ChrM    2   2    2  3 FALSE
2 ChrM    5   0    1  3 FALSE
3 ChrM    7   4    0  0  TRUE
4 ChrM    8   1    2  8 FALSE
5 ChrM    9   0    0 10 FALSE
```

---

In response to your comment:

As you are working with *data.table*, you could also use:

```
dflist <- lapply(dflist, function(x) x[, crit := (met + nmet >= 4) & (met>=bd)])
```

Comment: I get `Error in x[, "met"] + x[, "nmet"] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
> 
> is.numeric(met)
[1] TRUE
> is.numeric(nmet)
[1] TRUE`

from this. Any idea of why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: @GabrielHernandez Strange, it is working on the example data you provided. Could you check the updated code?

Comment: @GabrielHernandez Could include a `dput` of a part of you data in the question? E.g.: `dput(dflist[[1]])` or `dput(head(dflist[[1]],5))`

Comment: `dput(head(df[[1]],5))
structure(list(ID = c("ChrM", "ChrM", "ChrM", "ChrM", "ChrM"), 
    pos = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 11L), ori = c("+", "+", "-", "+", 
    "-"), cont = c("CCG", "CGT", "CGG", "CGA", "CGA"), met = c(0L, 
    2L, 0L, 2L, 2L), nmet = c(1L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 6L), bd = c(2L, 
    0L, 7L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("ID", "pos", "ori", "cont", 
"met", "nmet", "bd"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000005840788>)`

Comment: @GabrielHernandez It is working for me. I've updated my answer with code that is *data.table* specific.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `transform` without any anonymous function

```
 lapply(dflist, transform, crit = (met + nmet)>=4 & (met >=bd))
#  $d1
#   IDn posn met nmet bd  crit
#1 ChrM    2   2    2  3 FALSE
#2 ChrM    5   0    1  3 FALSE
#3 ChrM    7   4    0  0  TRUE
#4 ChrM    8   1    2  8 FALSE
#5 ChrM    9   0    0 10 FALSE

#$d2
#   IDn posn met nmet bd  crit
#1 ChrM    2   2    2  3 FALSE
#2 ChrM    5   0    1  3 FALSE
#3 ChrM    7   4    0  0  TRUE
#4 ChrM    8   1    2  8 FALSE
#5 ChrM    9   0    0 10 FALSE
```

---

Another option using `dplyr/purrr` would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
dflist %>%
        map(~mutate(., crit=(met+nmet)>=4 & (met >=bd)))
#$d1
#   IDn posn met nmet bd  crit
#1 ChrM    2   2    2  3 FALSE
#2 ChrM    5   0    1  3 FALSE
#3 ChrM    7   4    0  0  TRUE
#4 ChrM    8   1    2  8 FALSE
#5 ChrM    9   0    0 10 FALSE

#$d2
#   IDn posn met nmet bd  crit
#1 ChrM    2   2    2  3 FALSE
#2 ChrM    5   0    1  3 FALSE
#3 ChrM    7   4    0  0  TRUE
#4 ChrM    8   1    2  8 FALSE
#5 ChrM    9   0    0 10 FALSE
```

#### data

```
dflist <- list(d1=dfp, d2=dfp)
```